# Corona SDK: remove objects after delay

Tags: android, ios, iphone, coronasdk

Im creating clouds in my game which I wanna remove after 20 secs. The problem is that when I add the code to remove them, the clouds don't even appear, it seems they're removed right upon creation.

Here are the 2 ways I've tried already (none of which worked):

```
local function removeBody(body)

    body:removeSelf()
end

local function newCloud()
    local n = cloudNumber
    while n==cloudNumber do
    n = math.random(1,5)
end
    cloudNumber=n
    local cloud = display.newImage(imageNames[cloudNumber], screenW+30, screenH*0.2)
    timer.performWithDelay(6000, newCloud)
    cloud.myName="cloud"
    physics.addBody (cloud, {isSensor=true})
    cloud:setLinearVelocity(-25,0)
    cloud.gravityScale=0
    timer.performWithDelay(20000,removeBody(cloud))
end
```

and

```
local function newCloud()
    local n = cloudNumber
    while n==cloudNumber do
    n = math.random(1,5)
end
    cloudNumber=n
    local cloud = display.newImage(imageNames[cloudNumber], screenW+30, screenH*0.2)
    timer.performWithDelay(6000, newCloud)
    cloud.myName="cloud"
    physics.addBody (cloud, {isSensor=true})
    cloud:setLinearVelocity(-25,0)
    cloud.gravityScale=0
    --timer.performWithDelay(20000, cloud:removeSelf())
end
```

What should I do?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try the following code :**

```
timer.performWithDelay(20000,function() cloud:removeSelf() end)
```

**Instead of :**

```
timer.performWithDelay(20000,removeBody(cloud))
```

Keep coding................